# .NET Core Container Built with VSTS won't run on Linux

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, containers

I am using Visual Studio Team Services to build a .NET Core container with the `aspnetcore` image.  If I build the image from source on a Linux machine, I can run it and `curl localhost` works great.

However, the same exact code running in VSTS, building the same image, yields a different result.  I'm using the "Hosted Linux Preview" to build the image, which works.  The CI build succeeds and uploads the image to my private Azure registry.  When I run that image, on the same Linux machine mentioned above, it exits immediately with this error in the log:

`Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:...`

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY published .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ContainerPOC.dll"]
```

Comment: That is weird. Are you sure there isn't any difference between the two Dockerfiles?

Comment: Nope, I'm pulling the exact same code out of my VSTS Git repo and building manually on an Ubuntu Azure box.  My next experiment is to set that box up as the build agent...

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by what looks like a bug in the dotnet Publish task on VSTS.  When this command is configured:

`dotnet publish --output publish`

This is executed:

`dotnet publish --output publish/s`

The appended `/s` causes the output to go to a subfolder called "s" in the publish folder.  I changed the Dockerfile to reflect this location (the COPY directive) and all is well.

The error is reproducible:

- Comment out the `ENTRYPOINT` directive
- Build the image
- Run a container from the image and execute an interactive bash shell
- Execute the `dotnet` command and specify an assembly name that is not present in the working directory

The `Did you mean..?` error will appear.  Not a very descriptive error given the situation.